# How to push elements down to stack, Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, stack, message

I want to send message to user, but when I send message it pushing on top of stack, but I need to push it down like telegram or other messengers does.

here is code of stack settings

```
func setScrollView(){
   // messageScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 90, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: CGFloat( self.view.bounds.height))


    messageScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    messageScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.93, green:0.94, blue:0.97, alpha:1.0)

    messageScrollView.delegate = self

    messageScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomMessager.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    messageScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 90).isActive = true
    messageScrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    messageScrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    messageScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(messageScrollView.bounds.height))
    messageScrollView.addSubview(messageStackView)
}

func setStackView(){
    messageStackView.axis = .vertical
    messageStackView.alignment = .center
    messageStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
    messageStackView.spacing = 10

    messageStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageScrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true

    messageStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageScrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true

    messageStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageScrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    messageStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageScrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

and then I create a message and push it into the stack like

```
let messageView = MessageView(message: message)
messageStackView.addArrangedSubview(messageView)
messageView.setMyMessageView()
```

you can see the image below, there's messages on the top

how can I add messages on the bottom of stack?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
messageStackView.insertArrangedSubview(MessageView(message: message), stackIndex: 0)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.